# Cannot override text-align left css

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have a table where the `th` elements are `text-align: left`. In my CSS, I specified `text-align: center` to my `th` elements, but it's not overriding for some reason. Does anyone have any idea why? My table:

```
<table class="days_table" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th class="last_cell"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="last_cell"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
td, th {
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-right-style: dotted;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's my fiddle for reference:

https://jsfiddle.net/qg8xzf2y/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be more specific and it will override tables.less file. In this case:

```
td, table th {
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-right-style: dotted;
    text-align: center;
}
```

`table th` specificity will win against simple `th`